# How to load Key values in Dynamically Localizable.strings file objective c

Tags: ios

Any one help me at runtime, How to load key message value in Localizable.strings file objective C?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you at runtime?

Comment: At runtime i suppose to change message value with correspond key's in Localaizable.strings

Comment: Do you use NSLocalizedString method? http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/

Answer (score 0):

No way to do this.
Currently iOS supports the `localized (.strings)` files from `Bundle`. Bundle is read-only, so you can't change it's content.

Your requirement is possible if the `localized (.strings)` file is writable, for that it should be in document directory. But currently there is no way to read `localized (.strings)` files from document directory.

I don't know whether it can be a alternative for your solution or not: You can use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle()` for reading the localized content from other bundle.

Comment: my requirements runtime is there any possibility's for change/load key messages value in localized (.string)

Comment: @Uthaya: No way to do this

Comment: ok Midhun . i got u r point , is there any way to create dynamic localized strings file.Dynamic in the sense at run time.